# cannot customize csharp formatting on vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have been using alt+shift+f for a while now, for auto formatting my code.
However, the only thing it does is to fix the identation of the document

I did some research and found out that I could customize this formatting by following the instructions in: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options

I created the omnisharp.json both in my project root folder and my .omnisharp folder, however, none of them seems to change the behaviour of the auto formatting

Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!